# No option to "choose a service" on the "pay" section of gov.uk

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, saudi-arabia

I am applying from Saudi Arabia and as you can see in the image below, there is no option to pay by visa or cash or anything.

[image]

I tried 3 different devices and 3 browsers on each but this 'glitch' still wont change. I can not contact gov.uk because they only respond from monday to friday. Is there any solution for this? or any other way to apply for visa?

UPDATE(12/08/2018): when refreshing the page continuously, I noticed the options to pay appear for a split second and disappear. At some point I managed to stop the page loading at the exact time and found these options:(https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAMbw.jpg). Oddly, I cannot choose any of them.

Comment: Have you tried "change visa length"? Even if no other visa length suits your plans, it may at least shed some light on the situation if prices are available for other options.

Comment: Tried asking their tech support?

Comment: I am having the same issue and no idea about the possible solution.There is no alternate for making the payment and proceed.
I have tried even after changing the visa length.Its not showing the fees and any service options to select.
This is quite strange technical problem i suppose.

Comment: **I have the same issue. I tried to use the link provided above, however, and when I proceed with the steps, I received the below message:** *We are currently updating our online visa application service. You may be able to apply using our new service for visit visa applications if you are applying for a: - Standard Visitor Visa
- Marriage Visitor Visa
- 1 month Permitted Paid Engagements visa* **Then, they return me back to the old website**

Answer (score 2):

please use the link visa4uk.fco.gov.uk/home/welcome this is working and you can register and pay. The other link has errors in paying and will not work.

Comment: For anyone else wondering (like me) if visa4uk is some scam site, it is linked to by [this gov.uk website](https://www.gov.uk/apply-uk-visa), and I am therefore satisfied that it is genuine.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still having this issue, i managed to submit my application and make the payment on visa4uk, if you cannot create an account, find an existing account and "Apply for Someone Else" via that account!